# Adding enumitem key to nest lualatex-based environment that automatically punctuate lists

Tags: luatex, environments, itemize, enumitem

I have written a lua-based function to automatically puntuate itemized lists like so:

1. one`;`
2. two`; and`
3. three`.`

The `;` etc is automatically added. I can apply this as a command or environment inside an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment. What I would prefer though, is to pass `autopunc` as a key to the optional key-val args that enumitem provides. Eg. `\begin{itemize}[autopunc]`. Please see MWE below. The error that I am getting is `Error: You can't use \spacefactor' after \advance.\@->\spacefactor`

PS I'm open to suggestions on how to better achieve automatically punctuating my lists. Lua-based ideas are preferred.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{luacode*}
function AutoPuncItems(s, btwn, seclast, last) -- add btwn and sec and last options
    local it = '\\item'
    local s_item = '%s*'..it
    btwn = btwn or ';'
    btwn = btwn..' '..it
    seclast = seclast or '; and'
    seclast = seclast..' '..it
    last = last or '.'
    local _, n_matches = string.gsub(s, s_item, "") -- find num items
    s, _ = string.gsub(s, s_item,    seclast,   n_matches) -- replace all items with second last type
    s, _ = string.gsub(s, seclast,   btwn,      n_matches-1) --replace all but last(ie second last) with the between
    s, _ = string.gsub(s, '%s*xxxENDxxx', last) -- add the final char
    s = string.sub(s, #btwn-#it+1, #s)
    tex.print(s)
end
\end{luacode*}

\NewDocumentCommand{\AutoPuncItems}{ O{;} O{; and} O{.} m }{
    \luadirect{AutoPuncItems(
        \luastringN{#4xxxENDxxx},
        \luastringN{#1},
        \luastringN{#2},
        \luastringN{#3}
    )}
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{AutoPuncItemize}{ O{;} O{; and} O{.} +b }{
   \AutoPuncItems[#1][#2][#3]{#4}
}{}


%%% 
\SetEnumitemKey{autopunc}{% trying these don't seem to work
%    first*=\begin{AutoPuncItemize}, 
    before*=\begin{AutoPuncItemize},
    after=\end{AutoPuncItemize},
%% last=\end{AutoPuncItemize} % not a valid key, but this WOULD be nice
}

\begin{document}
    
    Works as desired
\begin{itemize}
    \AutoPuncItems{
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    }
\end{itemize}

    Works as desired
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{AutoPuncItemize}
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{AutoPuncItemize}
\end{itemize}

    This is what I'm trying to get, desired interface
\begin{itemize}[autopunc]
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: At least I found the documentation of package `enumitem` very unclear about the usage of `first` and `before`. It's not clear to me where _exactly_ these keys 'inject' the code. Is using `enumitem` a necessity? You can use hook mechanism of LaTeX to achieve what you want since you already have your lua-code working, but if you strictly need to stick to `enumitem` then probably report this to the maintainer. Either there is a bug in that package or it simply doesn't provide the functionality which we want here.

Comment: @likethevegetable Great question ! I had a partial/semi manual answer [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By printing the string that the Lua function `AutoPuncItems` recieved, I see `\fi  \item one \item two \item threexxxENDxxx`; it appears that an un-predicted `\fi` is passed.

I solved this issue by simply replacing `\fi`  with blank; this is added as the first line is `AutoPuncItems`: `s = string.gsub(s, "\\fi ", "")` .

Seems to work without issue. My only concern is there might be some unwanted affects from this. I see a warning:
`Warning:(67) (\end occurred when \ifnum on line 67 was incomplete)`, which makes sense since I'm erasing a \fi that I assume \ifnum used. Placing `\fi` after the environment resolves this. So, to be safe, I did the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{autopunc}
\SetEnumitemKey{autopunc}{
    before*=\toggletrue{autopunc},
    first*=\AutoPuncItemize,
    after=\endAutoPuncItemize,
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{\iftoggle{autopunc}{\fi\togglefalse{autopunc}}{}}
```

To re-use my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{luacode*}
function AutoPuncItems(s, btwn, seclast, last) -- add btwn and sec and last options
    --texio.write_nl('VVVVV \n'..s) -- troubleshooting
    s = string.gsub(s, "\\fi ", "") -- for some reason this is injected by enumitem
    local it = '\\item '
    local s_item = '%s*'..it
    btwn = btwn or ';'
    btwn = btwn..' '..it
    seclast = seclast or '; and'
    seclast = seclast..' '..it
    last = last or '.'
    local _, n_matches = string.gsub(s, s_item, "") -- find num items
    s, _ = string.gsub(s, s_item,    seclast,   n_matches) -- replace all 'item' with second last type
    s, _ = string.gsub(s, seclast,   btwn,      n_matches-1) -- replace all 'item' EXCEPT the last with the between
                                                             -- (all but second lines affected)
    s, _ = string.gsub(s, '%s*xxxENDxxx', last) -- add the final char
    s = string.sub(s, #btwn-#it+1, #s)   -- remove added stuff on very first item
    tex.print(s)
end
\end{luacode*}

\NewDocumentCommand{\AutoPuncItems}{ O{;} O{; and} O{.} m }{
    \luadirect{AutoPuncItems(
        \luastringN{#4xxxENDxxx},
        \luastringN{#1},
        \luastringN{#2},
        \luastringN{#3}
    )}
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{AutoPuncItemize}{ O{;} O{; and} O{.} +b }{
   \AutoPuncItems[;][; and][.]{#4}
}{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{autopunc}
\SetEnumitemKey{autopunc}{
    before*=\toggletrue{autopunc},
    first*=\AutoPuncItemize,
    after=\endAutoPuncItemize,
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{\iftoggle{autopunc}{\fi\togglefalse{autopunc}}{}}

\begin{document}

    Works as desired
\begin{itemize}
    \AutoPuncItems{
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    }
\end{itemize}
%
    Works as desired
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{AutoPuncItemize}
        \item one  % funck
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{AutoPuncItemize}
\end{itemize}

    This is what I'm trying to get, desired interface
\begin{itemize}[autopunc]
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{itemize}
\fi

\begin{itemize}
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Am I wrong or your great answer does not work with nested lists ?

Comment: It would not work (at least how I want it to) for nested lists. I would have to work a bit harder on the Lua function for that. Normally, when I use nested lists, I like to use a colon when introducing the sub-list. Would need to account for that, etc. Not an unreasonable request though, and if I find the time I might give it a try

Comment: @JeT - I fixed the issue and created a package that handles nested listts (you have to use autopunc if you want those punc'd): https://ctan.org/pkg/autopuncitems

Comment: Great ! thank you for the update, I clone your git on this. Thank you !

Comment: @JeT It should be available on MiKTeX or TeXLive soon, you might not need to manually install it then!